# Ruby: adding second element in array where first element is the same

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
[[1, 20],[2,30],[1,5],[4,5]]
```

In ruby how does one go through this array and add the second element if the first is the same with and output such as:

```
[[1, 25],[2,30],[4,5]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If order isn't important, inserting the pairs into a hash, adding if the key already exists, and then flattening the hash back into an array is a neat way.  In irb:

```
>> a = [[1, 20],[2,30],[1,5],[4,5]]

=> [[1, 20], [2, 30], [1, 5], [4, 5]]

>> a.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, p| h[p[0]] += p[1]; h }.to_a

=> [[1, 25], [2, 30], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: BTW: In Ruby 1.9, hash keys are guaranteed to be in insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

**A solution in Ruby**:

```
L = [[1, 20],[2,30],[1,5],[4,5]]
d = {}
L.each{|k,v| d[k] = (d[k]||0) + v}
```

A solution in Python:

```
L = [[1, 20],[2,30],[1,5],[4,5]]
d = {}
for k,v in L: 
    d[k] = d.get(k,0) + v
```

Comment: I wish I knew python but I don't and I asked for ruby

Comment: BTW - which to you like better? Ruby or Python

Answer (score 1):

You can do this (warning, the output is a bit garbled, you may want to convert to array):

```
myArray = [[1, 20],[2,30],[1,5],[4,5]]
outputHash = {}
myArray.each do |values|
    outputHash[values[0]] = outputHash[values[0]].to_i + values[1]
end
puts outputHash
```